# Spring 5: Programmatically register generic bean

Tags: generics, registration

Spring 5 provides programmatical registration using `GenericApplicationContext#registerBean`. Unfortunately, this method accepts only `Class` and not `ParameterizedType` to be able to retrieve generic typed bean.

Is there any other way how to register generic bean?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of factory methods available to register the beans programatically.

you can also make use of  `ConfigurableBeanFactory` from the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` and make use of `registerSingleton` to register the bean of class type.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext=SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory=applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("testBean", new Application().new TestClass<String>());
        TestClass<String> testObj=applicationContext.getBean(TestClass.class);
        testObj.testMethod("hello");
    }

    public class TestClass<T>{  
        public void testMethod(T t) {
            System.out.println("Test Method");      
        }       
    }   

}
```